# Mousedown prevents mousemove from triggering

Tags: javascript

I've made two image sliders, each image slider has one dragbar which can be triggered independently. The idea is that when you grab one of the dragbars, you can drag it to the left or right while holding down the mouse button. The width of the two images surrounding the dragbar will change according to the dragbar's position.

I created a boolean variable called drag which keeps track of the mouse events. While clicking on one of the drag bars and keeping the mouse down, the variable will be set to true. When the mouse button is released (anywhere in the window) the variable will be set to false.

When moving the mouse (anywhere in the window) a callback function (dragImg) will be triggered to check wether the drag variable is set to true. If so, the function will change the position of the dragbar and the width of the surrounding images.

My problem is: when the mouse button is being held down, dragImg will not be triggered. The function will only trigger when the mouse button is released. How can I trigger the dragImg function while holding the mouse button down?

```js
var warea = 0, locktarget = 0, xprev = 0, drag = false;
var dragbars = document.querySelectorAll('.drag-bar');
loadImg();
window.addEventListener('resize', loadImg, false);
dragbars.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('mousedown', lockImg, false);
    el.addEventListener('touchstart', lockImg, false);
});
document.addEventListener('mousemove', dragImg, false);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', dragImg, false);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', releaseImg, false);
document.addEventListener('touchend', releaseImg, false);
function loadImg() {
    var area = document.getElementsByClassName('drag-area');
    warea = parseInt(getComputedStyle(area[0]).getPropertyValue('width'));
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[class*=drag]');
    elements.forEach(function(el) {
     el.style.height = warea / 2 + 'px';
    });
    var img = document.querySelectorAll('[class*=drag-img]');
    img.forEach(function(el) {
     el.style.width = '50%';
     el.style.backgroundSize = warea + 'px';
    });
    dragbars.forEach(function(el) {
     el.style.left = '49%';
    });
};
function lockImg(ev) {
    var e = getEvent(ev);
    drag = true;
    xprev = e.clientX;
    locktarget = e.target;
};
function dragImg(ev) {
    if (drag) {
     var e = getEvent(ev);
        var x = e.clientX - xprev;
    var imgleft = locktarget.previousElementSibling;
        var wimgleft = parseInt(getComputedStyle(imgleft).getPropertyValue('width')) + x;
        var dragbar = locktarget;
        var wbar = parseInt(getComputedStyle(dragbar).getPropertyValue('width')) / 2;
        var imgright = locktarget.nextElementSibling;
        var wimgright = parseInt(getComputedStyle(imgright).getPropertyValue('width')) - x;
        var xbound = warea - wbar;
        if (wimgleft < wbar || wimgright > xbound) {
            wimgleft = wbar;
            wimgright = xbound;
        }
        else if (wimgleft > xbound || wimgright < wbar) {
            wimgleft = xbound;
            wimgright = wbar;
        }
        imgleft.style.width = wimgleft + 'px';
        dragbar.style.left = wimgleft - wbar + 'px';
        imgright.style.width = wimgright + 'px';
        xprev = e.clientX;
    }
};
function releaseImg() {
    drag = false;
    xprev = 0;
};
function getEvent(ev) {
    return ev.touches ? ev.touches[0] : ev;
};
```

```css
.drag-area {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.drag-area div {
    float: left;
}
.drag-bar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 2%;
    cursor: col-resize;
}
.drag-img-left    { background: url(https://dgbes.com/images/drag-ff-1.jpg) left top; }
.drag-img-right   { background: url(https://dgbes.com/images/drag-ff-2.jpg) right top; }
```

```html
<div class="drag-area">
    <div class="drag-img-left"></div>
    <img class="drag-bar" src="https://dgbes.com/images/dragbar.png" alt="dragbar" />
    <div class="drag-img-right"></div>
</div>
<div class="drag-area">
    <div class="drag-img-left"></div>
    <img class="drag-bar" src="https://dgbes.com/images/dragbar.png" alt="dragbar" />
    <div class="drag-img-right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to occur because it conflicts dragging with selection. Both events involve mousedown and subsequent mousemove. By adding `ev.preventDefault();` in `getEvent(ev)` my problem is solved.